# after login facebook, the page don't refresh

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a Facebook login to my page, but when I log into my page afterwards it doesn't refresh.

My button:

```
<p id="log_space"><b onclick="log_ty()" style="cursor:pointer">login</b></p>
```

and the function  `log_ty()` is

```
function log_ty(){

     FB.login(function(response) {
         if (response.authResponse) {
              console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
              FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
              });
         } else {
              console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
         }
     }, {scope: 'email,user_likes',return_scopes: true});

}
```

Comment: Really unclear what the issue is..   Why would it refresh?

Comment: when i logged mypage in. the string login is still login..

Comment: i wanna change the string logout, but not changing it.

Comment: the `js-sdk` doesn't refresh the page! and _"when i logged mypage in. the string login is still login.."_ you need to set a session for the user or use `FB.getLoginStatus()`